# How do you find the largest gap in a vector in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm

You are given the locations of various cars in the same lane on a highway as doubles to a vector, in no particular order.  How can you find the largest gap between neighboring cars in O(n) time?

It seems like a simple solution would be to sort then check, but of course this isn't linear.

Comment: O(n) time and how much space?

Comment: Where (n) is the number of elements in the vector? Yes, that can be done with a pretty basic loop.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - But he asked for a pretty C++ loop.

Comment: This is an interview question I've come across.  I'm assuming the space is unlimited.

Comment: @mats a neighbor in the vector isn't the neighbor on the highway, it's not sorted. It doesn't seem like it could be easily done in one iteration?

Comment: [Solution here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/dm-reading-assignments/Maximum-Gap-Problem.pdf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide the vector in n+1 equally sized buckets. For each such buckets, store the maximum and the minimum value, all other values can be discarded.   Because of the pigeonhole principle, at least one of those parts is empty, so the non-minimum/non-maximum values in either parts don't have an influence for the result.

Then, go over the buckets and calculate the distance to the next and the previous non-empty bucket, and take the maximum; this is the final result.

An example with n=5 and values 5,2,20,17,3. Minimum is 2, maximum is 20 => bucket size is (20-2)/5 = 4.

```
Bucket:   2    6    10    14     18     20
Min/Max:   2-5   -    -     17,17  20,20
```

Differences: 2-5, 5-17, 17-20.
Maximum is 5-17.

Comment: I couldn't exactly follow.  Do you mind elaborating just a little more?

Comment: *How* should the vector be divided into n+1 parts?

Comment: All parts should have equal size.

Comment: How can you divide a list with *n* items into a *n+1* equally sized parts?

Comment: You mean 'take max and min value, create n+1 buckets - ith bucket is responsible for a segment [i*(max-min)/(n+1), (i+1)*(max-min)/(n+1)]'

Comment: this is way over my head. :-D

Comment: I got it now. Hope OP gets it.

Comment: It seems in your example you divide into n buckets, not n+1.

Answer (score 0):

My Python implementation of ipc's solution:

```
def maximum_gap(l):
    n = len(l)
    if n < 2:
        return 0
    (x_min, x_max) = (min(l), max(l))
    if x_min == x_max:
        return 0
    buckets = [None] * (n + 1)
    bucket_size = float(x_max - x_min) / n
    for x in l:
        k = int((x - x_min) / bucket_size)
        if buckets[k] is None:
            buckets[k] = (x, x)
        else:
            buckets[k] = (min(x, buckets[k][0]), max(x, buckets[k][1]))
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if buckets[i + 1] is None:
            buckets[i + 1] = buckets[i]
        else:
            result = max(result, buckets[i + 1][0] - buckets[i][1])
    return result

assert maximum_gap([]) == 0
assert maximum_gap([42]) == 0
assert maximum_gap([1, 1, 1, 1]) == 0
assert maximum_gap([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]) == 2
assert maximum_gap([5, 2, 20, 17, 3]) == 12
```

I use a `tuple` for bucket's elements, `None` if empty. In the last part, I eliminate preemptively any remaining empty bucket by assigning it to the previous one (this works, since the first one is guaranteed to be non-empty).

Note the special case when all elements are equal.